# C++11 std::chrono subtract now and min

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

I feel like I'm going a little crazy with this one, but it just doesn't make sense to me. In my mind, if I subtract the minimum time point from any time point returned from a `now()` call, I should always get a positive duration, but that doesn't happen.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

typedef std::chrono::steady_clock myclock;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
        myclock::time_point min = myclock::time_point::min();
        myclock::time_point now = myclock::now();
        auto millis = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(now - min).count();
        std::cout << millis << std::endl;
}
```

Why does this print a negative integer and not a positive integer? (clang 3.3 or g++ 4.8.1)

Comment: Not necessarily related, do you want to output the time difference in seconds or milliseconds ?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I was trying to test to see if I was just overflowing because the millisecond result was too large. I'll change it back

Comment: You're overflowing the counter and getting a negative result

Comment: I get this same (mis)behavior with MSVC++ 2012 (aka Version 11.0)

Answer (score 4):

As has been pointed out this is the result of overflow. Remember that the minimum value a signed type can represent is about the same magnitude as the largest. If `now` is positive then the difference between `now` and `min` will clearly have greater magnitude than `min`, which means it has greater magnitude than the type's largest value can represent.

If you want to guarantee a positive duration then instead of using the minimum you could instead use a steady clock and then use the program start time as the base. The built-in clock durations are all specified such that a duration should be able to represent a range of at least a couple hundred years, so unless your program runs for longer than that you'll get positive durations.

Another option is to choose a clock where the epoch is known to be in the past and simply say

```
Clock::now().time_since_epoch();
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that "give me the minimum time" has traditionally been programmer shorthand for "give me a time that's guaranteed to be an expired time, no matter what someone picks for their expiration delay." I don't see how to do that with another relative time value.

Comment: That being said, I'm still upvoting this, because doing this, minus about 1000 hours, was the best solution I can see. But I don't see how this behavior isn't considered a bug.

Comment: @T.E.D. for that I would say `clock::min()` is the correct thing to do: `clock::min() < clock::now()` should always evaluate to true in practice. There's no need to do potentially overflowing arithmetic if you just need a time less than any current time. Also remember that even though 'traditional' time APIs don't distinguish in the type system between time points and durations, it's still important not to use a duration where a time point belongs or vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

You're **overflowing the counter** which, on my machine, is a `signed long long`

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits.h>
using namespace std;

typedef std::chrono::steady_clock myclock;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    myclock::time_point min = myclock::time_point::min();
    long long minl = reinterpret_cast<long long&>(min);
    cout << reinterpret_cast<long long&>(min) << endl;

    auto now = myclock::now();
    long long nowl = reinterpret_cast<long long&>(now);
    cout << reinterpret_cast<long long&>(now) << endl;

    cout << (nowl-minl) << endl;

    cout << "max of signed long long:" << LLONG_MAX << endl;

    auto millis = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(now - min).count();
    //std::cout << millis << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
-9223372036854775808
13924525439448122
-9209447511415327686
max of signed long long:9223372036854775807
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I think happens (from what I observe on my debugger in Apple-llvm 5.0):

`myclock::time_point::min()` returns the earliest timepoint, which is typically internally represented by an integer type, let's say `long long int`. The minimum of such a type is typically `numeric_limits<long long int>::min`, which is -2^63. This value is special, in that if you negate it you get the same value, through integer overflow (since the maximum long long int is 2^63 -1):

> -(-2^63) == 2^63 == (2^63 - 1) + 1 == -2^63 (by overflow)

Same logic applies to substracting.
All of this to say that integer overflow makes `(now - min)` actually equivalent to `(now + min)`, which is necessarily negative.

Comment: Note: actually signed integer overflow is formally *undefined behavior*, so your explanation is "pragmatic" but any compiler (and optimizer) may break havoc on this code.

Comment: Yeah, I was more reporting what I observed on my setup, which happened to display the same behavior as what LorenVS observed.

Answer (score 1):

Some readers (such as myself) may have landed here having wanted to guarantee that a time point has expired, no matter what the delay. This may have been written as

```cpp
//Init to far in the past so that on first run we perform the action
myclock::time_point prev_time = myclock::time_point::min(); 

// Compare current time with the past
myclock::time_point now = myclock::now();
auto delay = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(1000);
if ((now - prev_time) > delay)
{
   //This does not happen?
}
```

As explained in other answers this is due to overflow when the `(now - prev_time)` calculation produces a positive number larger than can be stored so wraps around to a negative number.
This can be solved by changing the order of calculation to avoid an intermediate value that might overflow:

```
if ((now - delay) > prev_time)
{
   //This works
}
```